# MDbg not found in VS 2012 Express for Windows Desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Previously I used VS 2010 Professional that I got from Dreamspark and I could use cmd line MDbg out of the box. But in VS 2012 there is no 'MDbg.exe' in the installation directory. Is it excluded from the Express edition, if so then is there any standalone installer available?

Answer (score 0):

MDbg.exe is part of the .NET SDK which can be downloaded separately from Visual Studio:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279